# Как мне подключить модуль и использовать namespaces, class?

Tags: c#, dll, pascalabc.net

Не спрашивайте у меня зачем мне это надо .

Создаю так значит проект на **PascalABC.NET** Form.
В основном pas файле у меня так примерно выглядит код:

```
uses Unit1;
{$reference Extensions.dll}
begin
  System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Window)
end.
```

Встречаю такую ошибку:

```
Windows.pas(2) : Ошибка при чтении сборки 'C:\PABCWork.NET\Windows\Extensions.dll'
```

***Extensions.dll*** файл почему то не могу подключить, в чём проблема?
По спецификации там находятся несколько namespaces.(Не спрашивайте откуда я это знаю )
вот так примерно выглядит его архитектура:

```cs
// там много using

namespace Math {
 class logarithm : Module {
      public static X()
      /// <summary>
      /// Number inverting. Example: O₁(n)
      /// </summary>
      public static inverting()
 }

    interface Module {
        interface General  {...}
        interface Geometry : General {...}
        interface Algorithm : General {...}
    }
}

namespace Logic {
    class Support {
         public static getType()
         public static getValue()
    }
}
```

Буду ждать ваших ответов .

**P.S(Не пишите мне по типу: "скачай компилятор для ассемблера" и т.п)**

**UPD:**
*16.08.2022* 
я в интернете нашёл вот такие строчки: 
`А с учётом того, что CLR по сути это мультиплатформенная машина, то заставить её использовать в других ОС, вообще, невозможно. Можно рекламировать, пропагандировать использование CLR - чем MS и занимается.`  
Коротко: моя задача состоит в том что мне надо создать рабочую c# библиотеку под все OS (Linux, MacOS, Ubuntu, Windows, Cosmos и другие ос) Значит она должна быть под COM или под CLR? вызвать на PascalABC.NET всё то что нужно из библиотеки написанной на C#.

Comment: Надо отличать управляемые библиотеки и нативные. Нативные импортами методов подключаются. А управляемые должны быть совместимы на уровне CLR. Ну либо есть еще COM, но это уже другая история.

Comment: @aepot - я вас не понимаю. COM это порты для микроконтроллеров или я туплю. Я не умею отличать  управляемые библиотеки и нативные. Я понял что у меня управляемая библиотека потому что в библиотеке ничего не импортируется , либо я вас неправильно понял. А как мне сделать совместимым на уровне CLR  и что это такое вообще?

Comment: Ну давайте погуглю: 1) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model 2) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime 3) https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/managed-code

Comment: я в интернете нашёл вот такие строчки:
```А с учётом того, что CLR по сути это мультиплатформенная машина, то заставить её использовать в других ОС, вообще, невозможно.
Можно рекламировать, пропагандировать использование CLR - чем MS и занимается.
```
Коротко: моя задача состоит в том что мне надо создать c# библиотеку под все OS (Linux, MacOS, Ubuntu, Windows, Cosmos и другие ос) Значит она должна быть под COM или под CLR? вызвать на PascalABC.NET всё то что нужно из библиотеки написанной на C#. @aepot

Comment: Нет, все проще. Выясняете, под какой версией .NET работает PascalABC.NET в разных ОС и пишете библиотеку под ту же версию.